# How can I Unhide every Excel sheet in a workbook using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I Unhide every Excel sheet in a workbook using VBA without having to list all the sheets like below.

```
Sub UnhideAllSheets()

    Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True
    Sheets("Sheet2").Visible = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Unhide all of the sheets in Excel using the following VBA code

```
Sub UnhideAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Credit to [This Website](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/524-excel-unhide-worksheets.html#methodb)